# Check if a file exists before creating it in Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, tasm

I'm a novice in Assembly programming and I was wondering how could I check if a file exists when I try to create one. In this program, I was expecting it to throw back an error if a file with the same name exists in the same folder. However, it just ignores it and creates a file regardless of whether or not it exists. Can someone enlighten me as to why this is the case? Oh and I'm using TASM to compile.

```
.model tiny
.stack 0100h
.data
org 01000h

file db 65,?,64 dup(?)
crstr1 db 'Enter file name to be created:$'
crstr2 db 'File successfuly created!'
db 'Press any key to continue . . .$'
crstr3 db 'File already exists or invalid name!$'


.code
main: jmp begin

begin:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
CLEAR
GOTOXY 2,4
DISP crstr1
INP file

    ;file check
    mov cx, 3fh
    mov dx, offset file
    mov ah, 4eh
    int 21h
    je error
    mov ah, 3ch
    mov dx, offset file
    mov cx, 0
    int 21h

    ;no error
    CLEAR
    GOTOXY 2,4
    DISP crstr2
    mov ah, 08
    int 21h
    jmp exit

error:
    mov ah,02h
    mov dh,6
    mov dl,4
    int 10h

    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset crstr3
    int 21h

exit:
int 20h
end main
end
```

Comment: You could use `int 21h / ah=3dh` first to open the file if it exists, and create it only if that fails. Or you could try using `int 21h / ax=4300h` to get the file attributes, which I would expect to fail if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: @Michael or even use ah=6ch.

Answer (score 0):

Use jc, not je. Error condition is returned in the carry flag.

Comment: Oh sorry, Its actually part of a larger program (file management) and I didn't bother to change it. Sadly, changing jc did not help much. Now its saying that a file exists even though it doesn't

Comment: @JohnKennethLee Debug your code. Make sure that before that int 21 your registers contain the right info and really point to the file name (check the memory too).